Need appointment date that is 1 visit before maximum appointment date
I need to find the last appointment date per person that is prior to their most recent appointment date.
Is there a way to use maximum(date) minus 1 or something like that?
I've tried maximum(appt date) <> 6/26/24 but that only give me False (boolean) - either can't be done or syntax is wrong
